# R - String column is considered as integer

Tags: r, string, csv, typeof

I encountered a very weird problem when reading a `.csv` file into a data frame `newdata` using `read.csv`.

One of the column is "Site", and it should be a string:

- When I look at the data frame using View I see that it contains values such as "www.google.com","www.facebook.com" etc.
- If I check what is the type of the column by `typeof(newdata$Site)`, I get the result "integer".
- If I check the frequency of appearance of each string using `table(newdata$Site)`, and I write this table to a `.csv` file, I get a proper frequency table for each value, with additional numerical value (e.g. one column with no name with numerical values, one column named `var1` with the sites strings (e.g. "www.google.com") and one column named `Freq` with the frequency).

I tried to create a new column which combines multiple values into one (e.g. "www.google.com" and "www.google.co.uk" into "Google") and I used `grepl`, then I realized that R treats the original column not as a string...

When I tried to subset this column only by `a = newdata[,"Site"]`, I got that
*`a` is of type factor*... writing it to `.csv` results in one long line of all the values....

What am I doing wrong???? I'm kind of new to these stuff and I really don't know what to do...

Thanks!!!

Comment: For everyones sake, try to format your text not as a bunch of words. And have a look at `str(newdata)` to see your column is a factor, and then search about factors (first step: `?factor`)

Comment: Did you happen to read the manual at all?  Probably not.  No one does.  They just post here first.  `help(read.csv)`. Specifically, the `stringsAsFactors` argument.

Comment: Hey @RichardScriven - I had no idea that this is related to reading from csv... But I appreciate your concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already dug quite a lot. You know that your column `Site` is a factor and it has `typeof()` integer.

To avoid coding strings as factors when reading in data, use:

```
read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

---

Factors are stored as integers, where integer gives the position of its levels. Try:

```
x <- gl(3,2,labels=letters[1:3])
#[1] a a b b c c
#Levels: a b c

typeof(x)
#[1] "integer"

levels(x)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

levels(x)[x]   ## equivalent to "as.character(x)", but more efficient
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c"
```

Comment: And since we have on-site documentation now, let's link to it (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1104/factors#t=201607221527562701029&a=remarks)

Comment: I just copied and pasted the link in.  but I wasn't asking you to do it.  Just adding it as a supplement. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ZheyuanLi ! Both for the solution and for the didactic attitude!